# Oldest Intel CPU generation that supports Zoom video conferencing

Tags: intel-graphics, hardware-rec, hardware-acceleration, zoom-meeting

I am trying to recommend a laptop to someone who will have to use it for a lot of Zoom meetings.

I have a personal and work laptop, and my personal laptop is overwhelmed with Zoom conferences (even 1:1 has glitches), whereas the work laptop does just fine with 100 people. I [compared the CPUs](https://www.cpu-monkey.com/de/compare_cpu-intel_core_i5_2520m-1090-vs-intel_core_i7_8650u-769) and found that there are large differences in the video codec support in both GPUs:

- My personal laptop has an Intel Core i5-2520M with the Intel HD Graphics 3000. That supports H.264 and AVC with encoding and decoding. But it does not support H.265, VP8, VP9, AV1 or JPEG. It can decode VC-1.
- My work laptop has an Intel Core i7-8650U with the Intel UHD Graphics 620. That supports the codecs H.264, H.265, VP8, VP9, AVC and JPEG with encoding and decoding, and also decoding of VC-1. It does not support AV1.

While researching the coded that Zoom uses, I found [an article](https://medium.com/@vsachdeva/zoom-video-conf-tool-at-scale-e86289c290b8) which said this:

> So Zoom chose to use H.264 Annex G (SVC) codec over H.264 (MPEG-4 Part 10).

[This article](http://highscalability.com/blog/2020/5/14/a-short-on-how-zoom-works.html) gives a bit more details on that:

> Zoom chose the SVC (Scalable Video Codec) codec over AVC. AVC is a protocol where you send a single stream and the single stream has a bitrate. If you want to send multiple bitrates you have to send multiple streams. This increases bandwidth utilization if you want to send multiple bitrates.
>
> SVC is a single stream with multiple layers. That allows sending a 1.2 mbs stream that has every resolution and bitrate you may need to scale down to given network conditions. In the past you could only do SVC with an ASIC. Now, thanks to Moore’s law, SVC can be done in software.

This suggests that Zoom indeed uses the SVC codec and that there is no hardware acceleration for it. The base coded seems to be H.264, but the GPU support cannot be used here? One just needs to have enough CPU power to get it done?

My phone is a [Xiaomi Mi A1](https://www.gsmarena.com/xiaomi_mi_a1_(mi_5x)-8776.php) with the Qualcomm MSM8953 Snapdragon 625 CPU and Adreno 506 GPU. According to [the specs](https://www.qualcomm.com/products/snapdragon-625-mobile-platform) it supports the H.265 (HEVC) and H.264 (AVC). Zoom runs just fine on it.

Looking into [Intel Quick Sync Video](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Quick_Sync_Video#Development) lists that only with Intel Haswell the support for for H.264 AVC, VC-1. So with that I would conclude that perhaps the Intel Core i5-2520M did not actually have decent hardware support for the Zoom codec, whereas the Haswell (Intel Core 4000) generation started to have it.

So which is the oldest Intel mobile CPU generation that still supports Zoom decetly?

Comment: Great research! My laptop with i5-5300U handles Zoom easily. That's a Broadwell chip which was a die shrink of Haswell without major architecture changes.

Comment: I have an Intel i5-3320 which I got in 2013. Intel Graphics 4000.  All drivers up to date. Windows 21H newest Insider. I runs Zoom just fine.

Comment: I'd be tempted not to minimum spec, but to minimum properly supported spec. Support in Win10 for all the old HD2/3/4000 series is poor & came very late (initially they were totally unsupported in Win10, except for the 4000 which did have one beta driver set.) The later 6-series has been supported throughout & would be my 'safe bet'.

Comment: Quick bit of research later - That would be Broadwell minimum, preferably Skylake or Kaby Lake, as they're leaps better & cheaper prices from new.